# How to get a fluid height with rows

Tags: html, css

How can I set a fluid height for each row? The rows would either be 4 or 6 based on the orientation as there are 24 total icons (6x4 or 4x6).

I was able to solve the 4 col and 6 col icon set and have a fluid width. However, I cannot figure out how to get the spacing between rows fluid for the height.

Also, I'm open to suggestions on how to improve the code as well if you think there's a better alternative.

Here's my code:

CSS

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 768px) and (orientation: portrait) {

/* Clear 4 columns */

  .profile {
    display: none;
  }

  .app {
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    width: 25%; 
  }

  .clear4 {
    clear: both;
  }

}


@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 768px) and (orientation: landscape) {

/* Clear 6 columns */

  .profile {
    display: none;
  }

  .apps {
  }

  .app {
    float: left; 
    text-align: center;
    width: calc(100%/6);
  }

  .clear6 {
    clear: both;
  }

}
```

HTML

```
<div class="apps">


</div><!-- .apps -->
```

Answer (score 0):

you mean the space between the app divs?

```
.app {
      float: left;
      position:relative;
      text-align: center;
      width: 100%; 
      margin-bottom:50px;
      margin-top:50px;

 }
```

have a look in here [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cwqw14jd/)

Comment: Well the images are 64x64. I'd like equal spacing between each app both vertically and horizontally. I was able to fix the width using width: calc(100%/6); for landscape mode and width: 25% for portrait. I just can't get the height spacing to be equal.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cwqw14jd/5/ I changed some of the image sizes and under the @media landscape put my new css. If you can help with the height that would be great. It has to be fluid as different devices would cause the icons to space out more. Think of an iPhone or Android phone when you rotate it. The amount of apps change and the spacing is always adjusted to be equal between them.